# Amazon S3 create user role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Is it possible to create user roles with low, medium and high permission? So that, we could grant permissions like read, write, full control to each user role.

Once we set up those log ins we would like to determine which folders belong where. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 allows you to restrict access permissions on bucket level. This can be achieved by creating different IAM users for different roles.
e.g. 
You can create 3 IAM users.

1. low-permission
2. med-permission
3. high-permission

After you create these 3 users, you need to attach access policy to the bucket. This can be done via AWS-CLI or AWS S3 Console. You need to use ARN or the IAM users you created above in the access policy.

Sample access policy :

```
{
    "Statement": [

        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/ROLENAME"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/ROLENAME"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/ROLENAME"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket/*"
        },            
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, AWS gives you very fine control over access to resources, in case of S3 you for subfolders of buckets and of course control over what actions can be taken. Manage your users and policies in IAM: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html

Also read about S3 Bucket policies:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html